# iPad: Changing the view according to the content when orientating (landscape / portrait)

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation, landscape

I understand that Apple will do a kind of autoresizing thing when iPad / iPhone change orientation and you can set views' autoresizing masks.

But what if the views' resizing is not that simple?

for example, I have a TableView and each cell has different number of letters. Assuming in Landscape mode, the TableView has perfectly built so that the TableView does not need to scroll down and all cells are listed perfectly ( I calculate the right font size for the texts in each cell depending on the width info)

If now I change the orientation to Portrait, yes, the TableView is narrowed, and the cells are messed up, they are narrowed (of course I want), but the TableView need to scroll down to see all cells. I know know the font sizes should be smaller so cells can be shorter

My question is:

So I have recalculate all font sizes if the orientation is changed? If I have 20 such TableViews laid in a paging-enabled ScrollView, I have to do this for all 20 * 10 cells each time when the user change the orientation??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES, either you need to create a two view OR change the existing controllers  frame. This is the only way to handle orientations.

Comment: OMG, this is what i can only say